# How would I ping between two pfsense WAN connections?

Tags: pfsense

This is my network connection:

[image]

They both are in vmware workstation, so they are virtual.

I want to ping from the pc to the server. I do not need internet connection, just a ping would be enough. I can ping between pcs and pfsenses, but the WAN connection between pfsenses do not respond. I turned on bogon and private networks in all interfaces. I used static routing like this:

[image]
[image]

I also added firewall rules to allow icmp packets on both interfaces like this:

[image]
[image]

Here, the pfsenses are in host only mode, so they do not have outside internet connection and they do not need it-a simple ping is enough.

How would I solve it?

Comment: If the outside network is 10.47.3.x why are the outside interfaces configured with a 110.110.110.x address?

Comment: I edited the connection addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Your WAN interface settings are wrong.

It should be something like this:

PFsense VM-1 WAN = 10.0.3.1 /24 Gateway = 10.0.3.2
Bogon networks un-checked.
Block private ip spaces = un-checked.

Pf-sense VM-2 WAN = 10.0.3.2 /24 Gateway = 10.0.3.1
Bogon networks un-checked.
Block private ip spaces = un-checked.

If you add any more pf-sense virtual machines, you will need to start adding either static routes, or enable dynamic routing advertisements.